# Migrate a workflow from SharePoint 2010 to 2016

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, 2016

I am trying to migrate a SharePoint 2010 workflow to a SharePoint 2016 site using SharePoint Designer.

For this I have followed the steps mentioned on this blog.

[Copy/Move SharePoint 2010 designer workflows](https://chanakyajayabalan.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/copyingmoving-sharepoint-2010-designer-workflows)

1. In the first(source) site, create the required workflow and publish it.
2. Now select Export to Visio option which allows you to save the workflow with a .vwi extension. (Refer this workflow hereafter as source workflow).
3. Now go to the destination site where you want the workflow to be copied, and create a new workflow with the same name as the previous one & publish it.
4. Now select Export to Visio option which allows you to save the workflow with a .vwi extension. (Refer this workflow hereafter as Destination workflow).
5. Now you will be having two .vwi files (one of source workflow’s – SourceWorkflowName.vwi  and other of the destination workflow’s – DestinationWorkflowName.vwi). Now add .zip extension to both the files. Now your files names should be SourceWorkflowName.vwi.zip & DestinationWorkflowName.vwi.zip.
6. Now open both the zip files, copy workflow.xoml.wfconfig.xml from destination workflow to source workflow. (Its destination to source and not source to destination).
7. From now on, we will not use the file DestinationWorkflowName.vwi.zip.  So ignore that file.
8. Remove the .zip extension from SourceWorkflowName.vwi.zip which gives you the   SourceWorkflowName.vwi file.
9. Now, go to the destination site, open workflows and click Import from Visio and browse to the SourceWorkflowName.vwi file.

But when I am importing it to Visio, nothing is happening.

Same thing I tried for SharePoint 2010 workflow, I am able to import a SharePoint 2010 workflow to another SharePoint 2010 site, but not in SharePoint 2016 site.