# Platform Sharepoint 2010 Designer workflows needs to convert the platform Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer

We have like 50+ SharePoint designer workflows and migrated to sharepoint online. When i open the workflows in designer 2013 it shows the platform type as sharepoint platform 2010.

Now as newly announced the from Nov 1st onward there is no workflow run of platform 2010.

So can anyone suggest me the good way how to change the workflows from Sharepoint platform 2010 to Sharepoint platform 2013. I know the architecture is different. but still tried the below scenarios

I tried exporting the visio and importing still it shows 2010
I tried copy the actions from 2010 to 2013 still didn't worked.

Please suggest me the best, easy and quick conversion of these workflows.

Appreciated for your help...!!!

Thanks,
Saan

Answer (score 0):

Install SharePoint 2013 workflow manager then follow this [thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/229197/migrate-a-workflow-from-sharepoint-2010-to-2016) - However, it does not get migrated easily, it depends on the workflow to workflow action - if you have relatively simple action, we could do using the above steps but for the complex workflow with the complex action does not get migrated as many of the 2010 actions are deprecated in the SharePoint 2013 workflow engine. For this, you may look at any third-party workflow migration tool like - [Dockit Migrator for SharePoint](https://www.vyapin.com/products/sharepoint-migration/dockit/sharepoint-migration-tools)

Having said these, while you are migrating the SharePoint 2010 designer workflow, use the [SharePoint modernization scanner tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/transform/modernize-scanner) and plan Power Automate in the long run.

Even, SharePoint 2013 workflow is not recommended in the long run. Starting in November 2020, SharePoint 2013 workflows will be turned off by default for new tenants. Microsoft will provide a PowerShell script to let customers to activate the SharePoint 2013-based workflow engine for tenant as needed.

**Note**:

- SharePoint Designer 2013 will not be supported after 2026, so time to think to convert in Power Automate.

MSDN Reference:

[Support update for SharePoint 2010 workflows in Microsoft 365](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/office-end-of-support-blog/support-update-for-sharepoint-2010-workflows-in-microsoft-365/ba-p/1505453#:%7E:text=SharePoint%202010%20workflows%20will%20be%20retired%20in%202020&text=Starting%20August%201st%2C%202020,2010%20workflows%20from%20existing%20tenants.)

Comment: Am facing a new problem the export visio import visio grayed out for 2013 platform designer workflows. tried installing the Service Pack 1 for Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2013 (KB2817441) 32-Bit Edition.